# Как изменить фон при наведении курсора (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

На сайте текущий пункт меню выделяется розовым фоном, при наведении на другие пункты выделяется серым. Не получается сделать его также розовым.
Пробовал писать

```
li:hover {
    background-color: rgb(217,149,148);
}
```

Не помогает.

Cайт [binarik.net](http://binarik.net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `style.css` замените

```
.nav li.active, li:hover, a:hover {
     background-color: rgb(217,149,148);
}
```

на

```
.nav li.active, .nav li.active:hover, li:hover, a:hover {
     background-color: rgb(217,149,148) !important;
}
```

Comment: только там нужно добавить !important, а то от body наследуется бэк белого цвета

Comment: @ Dmitry OnGamer, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

используйте sass или less, это позволит переопределять переменные bootstrap

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?